# Humans exploring an alien world; natives trapped in a strange machine

Tags: story-identification, aliens, space, space-exploration

This was a sci-fi exploration novel that I read about 10 years ago.

- A few humans land on a deserted alien world that is technologically more advanced. They do not know what happened to the original inhabitants but they go exploring to find out.
- They explore using the advanced transportation system with clear "bubbles" that they would step into and it travel through underground tunnels to anywhere in just a few minutes.
- There are other alien creatures on the planet; none have visible eyes but they can still see.
- The original inhabitants had trapped themselves in their machine they built. They are still on the planet but as "ghosts" and can only talk to each other and observe what the humans are doing.
- The woman who came with them dies at the end and one of the guys gets depressed because he loved her and enters the strange machine where he finds the inhabitants and directs them to the exit to leave the machine.
- Then they bring the woman back to life.

Comment: Elements of this sound an awful lot like [Soryandum](http://www.multiverse.org/wiki/index.php?title=Soryandum) in Moorcock's History of the Runestaff - perhaps you're getting multiple stories mixed up?

Comment: It was about 10 years ago. It is a novel. Other details is that they explored using the advanced transportation system. Clear "bubble" that they would step into and it would travel through underground tunnels to anywhere in just a few minutes.

Comment: Kind of sounds like Larry Niven's Ringworld... but not close enough I think.

Answer (score 5):

I know I'm too late, but this is a [novelization of The Dig](http://www.goodreads.com/book/show/866741.The_Dig) (the game) by Alan Dean Foster you're talking about.

Comment: Welcome to SFF.SE! It's never too late to answer, but for these questions it helps to provide some reasons why you think your answer is the one that the asker is looking for. I've added a link to the novel's description. Feel free to add details about it to your answer.

Comment: I thought it sounded very similar to The Dig. I didn't know there was a novelisation.